# how to connect Coldfusion to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

total newbie and totally lost...

I'm trying to setup coldfusion(8) with a mysql(5.5) database on a local (apache 2.2) webserver running Windows XP.

Coldfusion and Apache are running, but I don't know how to fiddle this in with MySQL.

I'm doing the following:
- Import file1.sql and file2.sql into MySql workbench (5.2) by reverse engineering
- Save this new model as base.mwb into my Apache htdocs folder
- Open the Coldfusion Administrator Data Sources
- Add new Source "myName", Database "base", localhost, 3306, root, password

When I try to add I always get *Unknown database 'base'* error.

I also tried to make a connection in MySQL or set up a new server instance in MySQL workbench, but these also fail because of *no database "base"*.

I guess I'm missing something (probably a database :-)... Thanks for some pointers or a dummy tutorial. I'm longing for something to show up in http://localhost...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have to guess that you are coming from a background using Access DBs.  MySQL and ColdFusion do not work together by have a DB file in the CF application.  CF connects to a running MySQL server somewhere on your network (even on the same machine) using a JDBC connection.  It does not look at a DB file and use that.  So you will need to install MySQL Server and then import the DB into that. Then use CF's datasources to connect with that.

Comment: I just found a nice tutorial - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-admin.html - I was missing the server, which I'm now trying to setup.

Comment: ok. I have the server running with my database. Still can't connect though from CFAdmin. I always get "unknown database 'name'"

Comment: is your database named "name"? And does the user you are connecting with have permission to access that DB? Perhaps at this point you need to ask a new question so that you can provide more details, like what you are entering into the CFAdmin fields.

Comment: I did :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203957/why-coldfusion-mysql-apache-isnt-running-on-localhost-if-everything-is-setup-an I had to configure the webserver by hand. Now everything is running smoothly. Thanks for coming back and asking!